# Will HTTP hyperlinks on HTTPS pages trigger mixed content warnings?

Tags: https, hyperlink

I am about switch to HTTPS for a site with about 1000 pages. All external libraries for the theme are secure and all internal ones will be changed over via 301 redirects.

What about anchor links within posts? If I am linking to my friend's URL which is not secure, because he doesn't have one for example within my text, will that also result in mixed content issues?

Comment: "and all internal [libraries] will be changed over via 301 redirects" - can you clarify what you mean by this? Linking to any internal "library" (as in a JavaScript library) via HTTP will result in a "mixed content warning", regardless of whether you've implemented a 301 redirect. (?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you're saying that, your site now serve with https and you want to link your friend site with http protocol.

Then it's totally fine, anchor links does not cause mixed content issue because it is **not loaded and render by browser**, while images, javascript, css, icons or other files are requested by browser(in src attribute) and if it is loaded without encryption then it cause [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) issue.

Answer (score 4):

If I am linking to my friend's URL which is not secure, because he doesn't have one for example within my text, will that also result in mixed content issues?

Ans: No.

Mixed content is when content used to render the current page itself, is loaded non-securely (or at least would if not blocked)

The user clicking the link would be taken to a non-secure page, but doesn't affect the security of the current page.